# Can't access board that I created

Tags: trello-boards, access-control

I created a board a few days ago called SCP Website Development. When I click to access it, I get this error message up:

> Board not found.
>   This page may be private. If someone gave you this link, they may need to invite you to one of their boards or organizations.

Other people in the organization are able to access it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your browsing data (cookies, cache, etc.).

If that doesn't work, try clearing your DNS cache. [Here](http://www.techiecorner.com/35/how-to-flush-dns-cache-in-linux-windows-mac/) are some instructions.